# Sending a POST request from Vue.js to flask

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, vue-component

I want to send a POST request from Vue component to Flask backend. 
I tried the following code:

in script.js:

```
finishGame: function () {
      this.gameStarted = false;
      this.$http.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", "hello")
          .then(function () {
            alert("POST")
          });
    },
```

in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
from model.words import Words

# Set up custom delimiters to avoid Vue.js conflict.
class CustomFlask(Flask):
  jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
  jinja_options.update(dict(
    block_start_string='(%',
    block_end_string='%)',
    variable_start_string='((',
    variable_end_string='))',
    comment_start_string='(#',
    comment_end_string='#)',
  ))

app = CustomFlask(__name__)
CORS(app)

word_gen = Words("model/word_lists/onegin.csv")


@app.route('/',  methods=['POST'])
def save_game_results():
    print("Game res!")
    return render_template('index.html', words=word_gen.get_random(500), words_num=word_gen.size())


@app.route('/')
def play_hat():
    return render_template('index.html', words=word_gen.get_random(500), words_num=word_gen.size())
```

The script contains more code, but the `finishGame` function runs for sure and only the piece staring with `this.$http` is ignored. The code doesn't generate any errors, but `save_game_results()` is never called when `finishGame()` is called.

I already tried:

1. Replacing `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/"` with `"/"`.
2. Replacing `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/"` with `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/go"` and `@app.route('/',  methods=['POST'])`
   with `@app.route('/go',  methods=['POST'])`

It hasn't worked.

Comment: [`this.$http.post(url, [body],[config])`](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#config) where body needs to be `Object`,`FormData`, `string` and your string is `"hello"`, convert is to `{foo: 'hello'}`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help, the python method is still not called.

Comment: have you checked the browser's console log? what does flask server log show? status code?

Comment: Checked, browser log looks as usual (no errors), flask log too -- okay status codes.

Comment: I tried your exact code and it worked for me [the alert shows](https://imgur.com/DxItWro). Assuming you've added `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>` at the bottom of your `index.html`

Comment: That is it -- I did not. Thank you! By the way, is there a way to catch such errors in JS / Vue? Nothing was complaining about import issues. (I am fairly new to JS)

Comment: Js errors can be found in your browser's developer tools > JavaScript console. Check [Shortcuts for different browser](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)